# Using the mid but with varying lengths.- excel

Tags: excel

In excel I am using the left,mid and Right functions to pull the 'suffix' of a string.

Example:

1234-1234567-1234

The prefix is 4 digits long
The Base is 7 or 8 digits long
and the Suffix is either 3 or 4 digits long.

I have the right formula as: =RIGHT(A6,LEN(A6)-FIND("-",A6)-8) to handle the varying lengths of the suffix

I need the MID formula that pulls the base section that can handle the varying lengths of the base and suffix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=MID(A1,1+FIND("-",A1),FIND("-",MID(A1,1+FIND("-",A1),9))-1)
```

(just for the part between the hyphens).

But Text to Columns with `-` as delimiter might be more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Given

`The prefix is 4 digits long The Base is 7 or 8 digits long....`

then you can use this formula

`=MID(A1,6,8-ISERR(MID(A1,13,1)+0))`

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
=MID(A1,6,FIND("-",A1,6)-FIND("-",A1,1)-1)
```